# jQuery load dynamic content and make it accessible with a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have little time studying JavaScript and jQuery and would like to learn how to load dynamic content in a div of the site by a button and the loaded content create a new url to be indexable and could share with friends social networks, etc.

I created a function that is called with the onclick event of a button. The function takes two parameters, the div where to load the content and the path where the content to be loaded is stored:

```
    function contentLoad(nameDiv, url)

{
     $(name).load(url, function() {

   });
}
```

button:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="contentLoad('#div-content','moon/content1.php')">Moon</a>
```

I do not know if I'll be doing well. The code still being very simple and charge me works perfectly content. But I'd like to load content would generate a new url that was accessible and that the link could be shared. How could I get it?

I think we need to store data loaded into a content with jQuery url when attempting to access, mount everything automatically and show visitors the web with dynamic content already loaded.

See if you can guide me in the process and that steps need to get it. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "client routes", using the hash tag in your url, and than some js lib which can handle this routes, for instance you can use director js, here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
 var author = function () { 
        // Load your content using AJAX
        $("#content").html("author");
    };
    var viewBook = function (bookId) {
        $("#content").html("viewBook: bookId is populated: " + bookId);
    };

    var routes = {
        '/author': author,
        '/books/view/:bookId': viewBook
    };

    var router = Router(routes);
 router.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Director/1.2.8/director.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#/author">#/author</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/books/view/1">#/books/view/1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can not see it very clear. What if I need to dynamically load about 100 different content? Should we modify the code to all links? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: It is up to you. The idea is to define routes ('/author' for example) than for each route define function which will be called, in that function you can do what ever you want, download as many contents as you want, In the example above I just wrote html into the #content div ($("#content").html("author");)

Comment: Forgive me ask you a stupid question. If I want to upload content div sun.php in your code how would you do?

Sometimes I'm drowning in a glass of water forgives.

Comment: Do you want to upload the content of the div with id 'content' to the url 'sun.php'? I thought that you want to download some content and display it in the div. To do the upload you can use jQuery methods 'get' or 'post'.

Comment: @pTRONICA: So it is an answer for you?

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me !!